# Does ngrx maintain separate state in separate browser tabs?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I am starting to implement ngrx store in my angular 9 app and need that separate browser tabs should maintain their own state. Does ngrx do that? i.e. I should be able to open separate invoice in different tabs hence the store should keep relevant data to that invoice in the given tab.

Comment: It's up to you to structure your state object accordingly so that each invoice has it's own state.

Comment: right but how can I keep it separate for separate tabs? i.e. If I have chrome tabs open for invoice 111 and 222, how do I keep the state separate? also do I associate that with the user that's signed in as that would also be part of the state/store

Comment: Well every tab is it’s own instance of your app so also has its own NgRx store..

Comment: I think the bigger problem is how you will run the angular app across multiple tabs. Or will each tab run its own instance of the app?